# Create joinWebUrl for a calendar Event , Microsoft-GraphAPI?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to create or get the ***joinWebUrl*** for any calendar event using MSFT graph API. When i enable online meeting it gives me Skype join url, but i want the team's joinURL.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for [Create Online Meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) using Graph API.One of the following permissions is required to call this API `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All` in delegated mode or Application mode.

Comment: @tTrinetra-MSFT - OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All is not available in my account. Just OnlineMeetings.ReadAll and OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite are available. Do I need to be admin to get these permissions?

Comment: OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite Could you please try with these permissions?

Answer (score 0):

While creating event pass these two params in the body to get the team meeting join URL

```
"isOnlineMeeting": true 
"onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
```